# impact of upgrading mySql from?

Tags: mysql

i have the following version on my devbox:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| version                 | 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)            |
| version_compile_machine | i486                |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu
```

thus i can use mysqlslap

but my production box sits with:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value              |
+-------------------------+--------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                 | 
| version                 | 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.8 | 
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)           | 
| version_compile_machine | i486               | 
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu
```

this version does not come with mysqlslap and i really need to db load test my prod box

if i upgrade my prod box to the sam as on my dev box,what implications will this have??
thank you